# CSS Flex + fixed size container height + disabling partially drawn items due to overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'll try to simplify my question:

I have a div container with a fixed height of 200px. Inside, I have a flexbox that shows vertical items. Each item has a FIXED height which should not change. I use `overflow: hidden` to prevent the last item to break out of that 200px. This works well.

**This is what I have with `overflow: hidden`**

[image]

**This is what I have without `overflow: hidden`**

[image]

But now, I'd like to take one step forward and prevent the rendering of the last item, if it's about to be cut and not displayed fully due to the container fixed height limitations and `overflow: hidden`

**This is what I really want, show only those items which are not cut fully or partially by the overflow: hidden;**

[image]

What's the best practice of achieving that? a kind of "**make sure all items fit in their fixed height inside the fixed height component and if one doesn't fit, don't show it at all**".

Using the lastest React. Probably doesn't matter but still.

I've made a small example here.
https://jsfiddle.net/hfw1t2p0/

Basically, I want to keep enforcing the 200px max height of the flexbox, but have some kind of automation that kills all elements which are partially or fully invisible, like items "4" and "5" in the example.

Please note the 200px flexbox height, and 50px item height are just examples. In reality, I need a flexbox that can weed out any item that doesn't fit fully in it... the max height of the flexbox or minimum height of elements is unknown until runtime.

Comment: Easiest way to do this with Javascript would be by using Intersection Observer API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API
I don't know if there is a pure CSS way to do it.

Comment: *"I want to keep enforcing the 200px max height of the flexbox, but have* ***some kind of automation*** *that kills all elements which are partially or fully invisible..."*. I added the JavaScript tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Thing : you should get benefits from using react:

To make Content Dynamically I'll add `gridItem` to state so that they're rendered dynamically.

```
state = {
    items: [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      " 4 I want this hidden, its partially visible",
      "5 I want this hidden, its partially visible"
    ]
  };
```

And For render:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="test">
        <div className="gridContainer">
          {this.state.items.map(el => {
            return <div className="gridItem">{el}</div>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[image].

[First Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-easley-kc88e)

### Here is the Cool Part:

Based on:

> Each item has a FIXED height which should not change

So that all items should have same height. The solution is to add:

1- ItemHeight

2- ContainerHeight

3-BorderWidth

to the state. Now with Some calculations + inline Styling You can achieve Your Goal:

first Your state will be:

```
 state = {
    containerHeight: 200, // referring to Container Height
    gridHeight: 50, // referring to grid item Height
    border: 1, // referring to border width
    items: [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      " 4 I want this hidden, its partially visible",
      "5 I want this hidden, its partially visible"
    ]
  };
```

in your `render()` method before return add this:

```
    let ContHeight = this.state.containerHeight + "px";
    let gridHeight = this.state.gridHeight + "px";
    let border = this.state.border + "px solid green";
    let gridStyle = {
       maxHeight: ContHeight,
    };
```

These are the same styles used in css but They're removed now from css and applied with inline styling.

`Container` will take it's max height property as:

```
<div className="gridContainer" style={gridStyle}> //gridStyle defined above.
```

let's see How `gridItems` will b e renderd:

```
//el for element, index for index of the element
   {this.state.items.map((el, index) => { 
            // i now will start from 1 instead of 0
            let i = index + 1,
            // current height is calculating the height of the current item
            // first item will be like: 1*50 + 1*1*2 = 52
            // second item will be like: 2*50 + 2*1*2 = 104
            // and so on
              CurrentHeight =
                i * this.state.gridHeight + i * this.state.border * 2,
            // now we should determine if current height is larger than container height
            // if yes: new Class "hidden" will be added. 
            // and in css we'll style it.
              itemStyle =
                CurrentHeight <= this.state.containerHeight
                  ? "gridItem"
                  : "gridItem hidden";
            return (
              // YOU'RE A GOOD READER IF YOU REACHED HERE! 
              // now styleclass will be added to show-hide the item
              // inline style will be added to make sure that the item will have same height, border-width as in state.
              <div
                className={itemStyle}
                style={{ height: gridHeight, border: border }}
              >
                {el}
              </div>
            );
          })}
```

Finally! in css add this:

```
.gridItem.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

**[Final Demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-leaf-licnu)**

**[Final Demo 2 with 40px gridItem height](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-snow-ig45r)**

**[Final Demo 3 with 300px container height](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-yalow-h1zv5)**

Comment: cool. thanks. I've already implemented something similar, but one that supports a multi-column Flexbox (in case the viewport width allows it). I hoped there would be a magical CSS like `flex-cut-overflow-items: {none, true, partials}` but turns out it doesn't exist... maybe it should. Anyway. thanks for your effort.

Comment: You're welcome! ... and unfortunately there is no such a css property :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the flexbox columns to send the overflowing items to another column and set the width to the width of the container to hide the items if you want to achieve this by plain flexbox css properties like you mentioned in the question. https://jsfiddle.net/kna61edz/

```css
.gridContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: yellow;
    max-height: 200px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 52px;
}
```

The only difference is that you won't be seeing the yellow background of the gridContainer but you can set the background in the enclosing div like in the picture below but it will adapt to the height of the child divs.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

why not test elements with `document.getElementById('element').clientHeight`?
check the container size and find which element is visible or not.